# OverflowError with Matplotlib and datetime

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, tkinter

I am getting an overflow error when I try and make a scatter plot with a datetime:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

list_data  = ['2016-10-06', '2016-09-24', 55, 'dummy', 0.510823, 0.29431]
columns    = ['master', 'slave', 'baseline', 'coh', 'coh_mean', 'coh_std']
dict_data  = dict(zip(columns, list_data))
data       = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_data, orient='index').T
data.slave = pd.to_datetime(data.slave)
fig, axes  = plt.subplots()
axes.scatter(data.slave, data.baseline)
plt.show()
```

I've tried a variety of things, such as using `datetime.strptime(`), changing matplotlib backends but only have been isolate the problem to the datetime format (works fine if it's a string).

Plotting without scatter `(axes.plot(), axes.plot_date())` works fine, but I eventually need to color the scatter points, which the scatter method seems best suited for.

EDIT: 
Plotting the values of the panda series
    `axes.scatter(data.slave.values, data.baseline.values)`
Results in an empty figure object.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot plot a pandas series with `scatter`. What you want is to plot its values only.

```
axes.scatter(data.slave.values, data.baseline.values)
```

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

list_data  = ['2016-10-06', '2016-09-24', 55, 'dummy', 0.510823, 0.29431]
columns    = ['master', 'slave', 'baseline', 'coh', 'coh_mean', 'coh_std']
dict_data  = dict(zip(columns, list_data))
data       = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_data, orient='index').T
data.slave = pd.to_datetime(data.slave)
fig, axes  = plt.subplots()
axes.scatter(data.slave.values, data.baseline.values)
plt.show()
```

results in

[image]

Comment: I should have mentioned I tried that, but it results in an empty plot.

Comment: No, it results in a plot with exactly one scatter point. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. My plot was blank though, it seems because of the way I constructed the data, with the from_dict method or perhaps the transpose. Any idea what is happening under the hood here?

Comment: No, this has nothing do do with the dataframe. I updated the code in the answer, which is now the same as yours and it still gives the same plot.

Comment: Very strange; this produces an empty plot for me, even with various backends. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47101239/matplotlib-plot-changes-with-different-data-structure-same-data