# Matplotlib plot changes with different data structure (same data)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Creating a scatter plot with matplotlib is giving me an empty or correct plot depending on whether I construct a pandas dataframe from a dictionary with `from_dict` or from a list with simply `pandas.DataFrame`.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
list_data  = ['2016-10-06', '2016-09-24', 55, 'dummy', 0.510823, 0.29431]
columns    = ['master', 'slave', 'baseline', 'coh', 'coh_mean', 'coh_std']
dict_data  = dict(zip(columns, list_data))
data       = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_data, orient='index').T
data.slave = pd.to_datetime(data.slave)
fig, axes  = plt.subplots()
axes.scatter(data.slave.values, data.baseline.values)
plt.show()
```

results in:

[empty plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Quytj.png)

while:

```
list_data  = ['2016-10-06', '2016-09-24', 55, 'dummy', 0.510823, 0.29431]
columns    = ['master', 'slave', 'baseline', 'coh', 'coh_mean', 'coh_std']

data = pd.DataFrame([list_data], columns=columns)
data.slave = pd.to_datetime(data.slave)
fig, axes  = plt.subplots()
axes.scatter(data.slave.values, data.baseline.values)
plt.show()
```

results in:

[correct plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mR3k.png)

MacOS Sierra 10.12.6 || python: v3.6.2 || matplotlib: v2.0.2 || pandas v0.20.3

I've tried various backends as well as python: v2.7 to no avail.
Can anyone explain why this is happening (or even reproduce): [OverflowError with Matplotlib and datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47087883/overflowerror-with-matplotlib-and-datetime/47094071?noredirect=1#comment81149515_47094071))?

Comment: As already commented on the other question, I cannot reproduce this. I get the same output with both codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because creating a dataframe from a dictionary (using the above method) it is not inferring datatypes. It may in later versions but I'm running `0.20.1`. For demonstration purposes I renamed your dfs:

```
df_fromdict       = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_data, orient='index').T
df_fromdict.slave = pd.to_datetime(df_fromdict.slave)

df_fromdict.dtypes
master              object
slave       datetime64[ns]
baseline            object # notice here your baseline column is not recognized as int
coh                 object
coh_mean            object
coh_std             object
dtype: object


df_fromlist = pd.DataFrame([list_data], columns=columns)
df_fromlist.slave = pd.to_datetime(df_fromlist.slave)

df_fromlist.dtypes
master              object
slave       datetime64[ns]
baseline             int64 # recognized as int by default
coh                 object
coh_mean           float64
coh_std            float64
dtype: object
```

Try the following as a test and your first scatterplot should appear as expected:

```
fig, axes  = plt.subplots()
axes.scatter(df_fromdict.slave.values, df_fromdict.baseline.astype(int).values)
plt.show()
```